# does down(semaphore) and down_intterruptible(semaphore) must be called from system call?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, semaphore, interrupt-handling, interrupt

i was asked if i can use the The following functions :

```
void down(struct semaphore* sem);
int down_intterruptible(struct semaphore* sem);
```

ONLY from system call ?

Answer (score 1):

No, they are fine to use from any kernel context where you are allowed to sleep.  For example, a kernel thread may do `down()`.  Of course a timer function cannot, since `down()` may sleep.  You definitely do not need to be directly handling a system call.

As an aside, in modern kernels, `struct mutex` and `mutex_lock()` are preferred to `struct semaphore` and `down()` except for cases where you truly need counting semaphores, or need to release the semaphore from a different context than where it is acquired.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. You can try locking the semaphore anywhere from kernel except the interrupt context. Failing to acquire a semaphore will put your task to sleep and you cant afford to put your interrupt handler to sleep and cause a deadlock.

you can use